# Maintain sessions in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies

I am working on chrome extensions. I did a basic login and registration in chrome extension. What I am facing difficulty is for every tab i have to login and register.

Manifest.json:

```
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Login Signup",
      "description": "User profile extension ",
      "version": "1.0",
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["login_cookies.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "options_page": "login_cookies.html",
      "content_scripts": [ {
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["user_login.js","login_cookies.js","user_registration.js"]
      }
      ],
      "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/login/"],
      "ids":["gljlejolcfnidahkdnllngpebdgeippm"] 
      },
      "permissions": [
        "identity"
      ]
    }
```

Login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User</title>
    <script src="user_login.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="test2" action="login_cookies.html" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="userpassword" class="form-control" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="loginSubmit" type="submit">OK</button>
    </div>   
    <div>
      <a href="default.asp" target="_blank"><img src="facebook_login.png"  style="width:100px;height:50px;border:0;" alt="HTML tutorial" >
      </a>    
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="default.asp" target="_blank"><img src="google_login.png" alt="HTML tutorial" >
      </a>    
  </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

LoginCookies.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User</title>
        <script src="login_cookies.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkCookie()">
        <div>
            <h3>Hello</h3>
            <input type="text" name="text" id='setText'/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

LoginCookies.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkCookie, false);

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (120*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    document.getElementById("setText").innerHTML = cvalue;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var useremail = localStorage.getItem("email ");
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome " + user);
    } else {
       //user = prompt("Please enter your name:",useremail);
       if (useremail != "" && useremail != null) {
           setCookie("username", useremail, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

I have to maintain LoginCookies.html after user login in the extension for all tabs whenever user clicks extension icon. Suggest me how to maintain that html using cookies

Comment: Use `localStorage` instead of cookies.

Comment: Ok i have to store email in local storage and then i can get email from local storage. But every time i have to login for every page. One thing I cannot understand is after login in the chrome extension i have to maintain the login details in chrome extension for every new tab

Comment: Cookies are saved domain wise. I am guessing in every new tab you have a diffrent url.

Comment: In my code i have to store email in local storage after login in Login.js. I can get this email in LoginCookies but how to maintain time like sessions. Please edit the above code so that i can understand.

Comment: Ok, so just like you are storing email in the localstorage you can store other auth details that you want to maintain after login in localstorage as well. Hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: ok  i understand instead of email we have to store other details. But my question is how to display the details of user in chrome extension. I tried but for every tab when i click the extension icon i have to login again. it is not showing the details of user in other tab.

Comment: Simply use `localStorage.getItem` to get any item stored in the localstorage and display it the chrome extension using javascript. Also make sure the name of the item should be correct no leading and trailing spaces should be there.